# My overfitted decision tree regressor gives better result than pre-pruned tree?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees, overfitting, hyperparameter-tuning, metric

I create a decision tree regressor without giving any parameters. The resulting tree has 6255 leaf nodes (out of 6348 entries of train set) and depth of 39. Most probably it has overfitted. But its performance is quite good with R-squared value around 0.79 and MSE 280. Now I create another tree with adjusting max_depth to around 15 and max_leaf to around 400 but performance is not improving. I don't know how can an overfit tree have such good testing accuracy? And which values should I select for hyperparameters? Will randomsearchcv help here?

Comment: How did you measure performance?

Comment: R-squared and MSE

Comment: On training set, validation set, testing set? How are the splits done? Have you accounted for data leaks when doing the splits?

Comment: How does the regression regults look when plotted on a scatter? R-squared of 0.79 and MSE 280 can be horribly bad, depending on the shape/scale of the data.